# XCode 13.2.1 Executable Not Found

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode13.2

I am trying to build my react-native ios application on an iPhone 12 (ios 14.3) simulator. After the build succeeds, I am getting an error dialog at the end reading:

"Executable Not Found

/userFolder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eMobility-fzupihuygopdozakomhycmxkpemd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/eMobility.app is not a valid path to an executable file. Please rebuild the project to ensure that all required executables are created. Check your project settings to ensure that a valid executable will be built
"

**Error details:**

"

```
Executable Not Found
Domain: DVTMachOErrorDomain
Code: 5
Recovery Suggestion: /userFolder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eMobility-fzupihuygopdozakomhycmxkpemd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/eMobility.app is not a valid path to an executable file. Please rebuild the project to ensure that all required executables are created. Check your project settings to ensure that a valid executable will be built.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-01-12 14:26:52 +0000";
}
```

I am using the latest XCode version : 13.2.1.

I want to say that the build was working before without changing anything (same simulator). So I am guessing it comes from the latest XCode update

Comment: try to have a look at this thread : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687721

Comment: @chikabala I have tried that already and it is not working

Comment: I'm getting the same after upgrading to react native 0.68 - did you find a solution?

Comment: If soultion not found then can you give me ss of errors and explain detailed scenario so I can help.

Answer (score -1):

run npm install before run the project from XCode